# Change the default compiler from lcc to MSVS running in Rapid accelerator mode

Tags: matlab, simulink, s-function, lcc

I am trying to run a Simulink file which contain S-functions along with other Simulink blocks in rapid accelerator mode. When tried to build the executable I am getting a error to change the compiler from **LCC** to supported compilers.

**Note**: Matlab documentation suggests **lcc** compilers are incompatible with S-functions

Steps tried:

Running `mex -setup` I was able to select **MSVS** compiler already installed in my computer. But again while trying to build for rapid accelerator target, Simulink is taking **LCC** compiler pre-installed with its installation.

Can anyone suggest a work-around, what I am expecting is:

-Ways to change the default compiler (**LCC**) to another compiler preferably **MSVS** (installed) for building Rapid Acceleration target
-Ways of overriding the **LCC** selection by Simulink to another compiler selection.

Comment: Did you change both the C compiler and the C++ compiler with `mex setup`? By default it sets only the C compiler, there should be links to other languages when you do that though.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I think you might be right. I did change the C compiler but may have left the C++ compiler to configure. Thanks!

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks a lot it worked. Brain fade for me. My bad!

Comment: Wonderful! Please add an answer so that other people with this issue can find it! These comments can be deleted easily.

Answer (score 0):

**Background**:The default compiler for C++ in Simulink is lcc which is packaged with the installation.
According to [Supported compilers in matlab](https://in.mathworks.com/support/requirements/supported-compilers.html)  it is observed that lcc doesn't S-functions and have to select another compiler installed in the system. In my case MSVS2015 satisfied all my model requirements.

To change the default compiler run

`mex -setup c` and `mex -setup c++` to change the C and C++ compilers.

**Solution**:For my above question I had forgot to set C++ compiler and only changed C compiler to MSVS which caused the erroneous runs.